# Custom Hide Sidemap MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using a bootstrap template that has sitemap. How to hide a node in Sitemap from a controller.
Here is example of My MvcSiteMap. I want to hide SamplePage Node by a condition in controller.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" clickable="false" icon="fa fa-home" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!"></mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Dashboard" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" icon="fa fa-dashboard"></mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Sample Page" controller="Sample" action="Index" icon="fa fa-info">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Master" clickable="false" icon="fa fa-info"></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC SiteMap provider -- How to 'hide' single items in the actual menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007065/asp-net-mvc-sitemap-provider-how-to-hide-single-items-in-the-actual-menu)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it by condition in your controller, you could achieve it only on this way, you should probably create a property in object that you'r returning from a controller, and that propertly might be called for example :

```
public static bool HideSamplePage {get; set;}
```

And what you might do on your View is next (I hope you know that Razor code blocks are enclosed in @{ ... })

```
@if(Model.HideSamplePage)
{
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" clickable="false" icon="fa fa-home" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dashboard" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" icon="fa fa-dashboard"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Master" clickable="false" icon="fa fa-info"></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
}
else
{
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" clickable="false" icon="fa fa-home" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Dashboard" controller="Dashboard" action="Index" icon="fa fa-dashboard"></mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Sample Page" controller="Sample" action="Index" icon="fa fa-info">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Master" clickable="false" icon="fa fa-info"></mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
}
```

In code above I said if set state of property HideSamplePage to true, 
then `<mvcSiteMapNode title="Sample Page" controller="Sample" action="Index" icon="fa fa-info">` wont be shown/generated.

else
show `SamplePage` also

Comment: How can i make condition in MvcSiteMapNode??  because the  file is in XML?